# Joining different length data frames with different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two sets of data, each in a separate data frame. This is because one is derived from an Excel spreadsheet and the other by automatic iteration of raw data files.
Both data frames have one thing in common: a first column containing a uniform timestamp information for the observations in them. df1 contains data on humidity and temperature (variables: timestamp, hum, temp), and df2 contains an oxygen, power and a time variable (variables: timestamp, O2, power, time).

Ideally, both df1 should contain all timestamped observations that df2 contains as well. Additionally, df1 contains some extra observations that need to be cleansed.

I would like to "join" both data frames, such that for each timestamp, all variable values from both df are joined (i.e. variables: timestamp, hum, temp, O2, power, time). Those observations that only occur in df1 should be removed.

Is there any smart way of doing that?

Kind regards
kruemelprinz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're just looking for a simple left_join. This can be done via dplyr with

```
left_join(df2, df1)
```

which will only return rows where df2 and df1 match in the timestamp column. (This drops all of the extra observations in df1).

A base R implementation is:

```
merge(x = df2, y = df1, by = "timestamp", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as correct by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. Happy to help.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for the hint :)